# Vaxis on Google chart not showing when used with jquery

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I want to use Google Charts with jquery collapsible html. However when the working google chart code is put into  jquery collapsible html the values on the vaxis do not show

I have tried the google code outside of jquery and it works, also i have tried several versions of of jquery and looked on the internet for similar examples, but i'm  completely stuck

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demob">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demob" class="collapse">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
          'packages': ['corechart']
        });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['time', 'temperature'],
            [0, 36.75],
            [1, 36.75],
            [2, 36.75],
            [3, 36.75],
            [4, 36.75],
            [5, 36.81],
            [6, 36.81],
            [7, 36.81],
            [8, 36.81],
            [9, 36.81],
            [10, 36.81]

          ]);


          var options = {
            title: 'FarSite Temperature',
            'width': 1000,
            'height': 600,
            vAxis: {
              format: 'decimal'
            },
            curveType: 'function',
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Time'
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'Temperature',
              viewWindow: {
                max: 40,
                min: 20
              },
              format: '0'
            },
            legend: 'none',
            bar: {
              groupWidth: '95%'
            }
          };

          var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
            container.className = null;
          });
          chart.draw(data, options);
        }
      </script>
      <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>





      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The google charts code works alone but doe not show values on the vaxis when inside jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a result of drawing the chart in a hidden container.
the chart cannot properly calculate the placement of all the elements.

instead, wait until the chart is shown, before drawing for the first time...

```
      $('#demob').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
        chart.draw(data, options);
      });
```

see following working snippet...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
    <p>Click on the button to toggle between showing and hiding content.</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demob">Simple collapsible</button>
    <div id="demob" class="collapse">
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        google.charts.load('current', {
          packages: ['corechart']
        }).then(function () {
          var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ['time', 'temperature'],
            [0, 36.75],
            [1, 36.75],
            [2, 36.75],
            [3, 36.75],
            [4, 36.75],
            [5, 36.81],
            [6, 36.81],
            [7, 36.81],
            [8, 36.81],
            [9, 36.81],
            [10, 36.81]
          ]);

          var options = {
            title: 'FarSite Temperature',
            width: 1000,
            height: 600,
            vAxis: {
              format: 'decimal'
            },
            curveType: 'function',
            hAxis: {
              title: 'Time'
            },
            vAxis: {
              title: 'Temperature',
              viewWindow: {
                max: 40,
                min: 20
              },
              format: '0'
            },
            legend: 'none',
            bar: {
              groupWidth: '95%'
            }
          };

          var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
          google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
            container.className = null;
          });

          $('#demob').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            chart.draw(data, options);
          });
        });
      </script>
      <div id="chart_div" style="width: 800px; height: 600px"></div>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```